# How do I encode a List of custom dataclasses into JSON

Tags: python, json

So I have a custom dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class item:
    name: str
    price_range: [int, int]
```

And now I have a few of these objects in an array like:

```
array = [item("Toy", [100, 200]), item("Car", [500, 600])]
```

How would I convert this to json, Ive tried other things but they don't seem to work on Lists.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a built in `@dataclass`, you can also use the `asdict` methods built into the same module. Something like the following, just scaled to your list

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict)

```py
@dataclass
class item:
    name: str
    price_range: [int, int]

my_dict = asdict(item("toy", [100, 200]))
```